# Why can't I access a subfield of mongoose object using populate?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose,
I have **program** and **customer** modles croosponudg to the collections I have in mongoDB.

The **program** model has refrence to customer:

```
customerId: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,  ref: 'Customer', required: true }
```

and one of the attribute of customer is lastname:

```
 lastname: {type: String, required: true, max: 20}
```

I want to show docs represent all the program details with the last name of the customer.

I try to do this with populate **here is the code**:

```
router.get('/list', (req, res) => {
Program.find().populate('customerId').exec((err, docs) => {
    if (!err) {
        res.render("program/list", {
            list: docs
        });
    }
    else {
        console.log('Error in retrieving program list :' + err);
    }
});
```

});

but I only success to get the whole customer object and not to its subfileds.

```
<td>{{this.customerId}}</td>
```

gives me-

{ _id: 5fa4f5f6b600c83ac8695aa3, organization: 5fa4f2304838400550914f3d, id: '000000018', key: '000001', lastName: 'abb', firstName: 'cdd', city: 'aaaaa', street: 'aaaa', anotherPhone: null, zip: '75265', phone: '0354' }

but

```
<td>{{this.customerId.lastName}}</td>
```

gives me nothing

and in the console i get:

model {$**: InternalCache, isNew: false, errors: undefined, _doc: {…}, $init: true}
controllers/programController.js:83
**v (get):ƒ () {\n        return this.get.call(this.$**.scope || this, path);\n      }
**v (set):ƒ (v) {\n        return this.$set.call(this.$**.scope || this, path, v);\n      }
_doc:{address: {…}, _id: ObjectID, organization: ObjectID, id: '000000018', key: '000001', …}
_id (get):ƒ () {\n        return this.get.call(this.$**.scope || this, path);\n      }
_id (set):ƒ (v) {\n        return this.$set.call(this.$**.scope || this, path, v);\n      }
$**:InternalCache {strictMode: true, selected: {…}, shardval: undefined, saveError: undefined, validationError: undefined, …}
$init:true
address (get):ƒ ()
address (set):ƒ (v) {\n        if (v instanceof Document) {\n          v = v.toObject({ transform: false });\n        }\n        const doc = this.$__.scope || this;\n        return doc.$set(path, v);\n      }
errors:undefined

Could you help me how to get access to the subfields of customer?

I hope I'm clear enough.

thank's

Comment: Where is the code of the populate option?

Comment: I added the code above.

Comment: You have lastname and lastName, maybe this is the typo error?

Comment: I thinked so but no,I can't accses to any attribute of the customer. thank you!